# Preprocessor #ifndef

Tags: c, header-files, ifndef

Assume I have `a.h` which includes the following:

```
<stdbool.h>
<stddef.h>
<stdin.h>
```

Assume I also have `b.h` which also includes `<stdbool.h>`. If `a.h` has the `#ifndef` preprocessor definition statement in it and `b.h` doesn't. Will `a.h` include only what hasn't been included in `b.h`? So when `b.h` includes `a.h`, will `a.h` include `stddef.h` and `stein.h` and not re-include `stdbool.h` or are those preprocessor definition functions only used to see whether this whole class is redefined, and not specific functions within it?

EDIT:

Also, assume `b.h` includes another header file which includes `stdbool.h` -that makes `b.h` have `stdbool.h` both from that class and `a.h`. Will that cause errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All C standard headers must be made such that they can be included several times and in any order:

> Standard headers may be included in any order; each may be included
>   more than once in a given scope, with no effect different from being
>   included only once

Answer (score 1):

If `stdbool.h` itself has include guards (`#ifndef`) then everything will be fine. Otherwise you may indeed end up including some headers twice. Will it cause a problem? It depends. If the twice-included header contains only declarations then everything will compile - it will just take few nanoseconds longer. Imagine this:

```
int the_answer(void); // <-- from first inclusion
int the_answer(void); // <-- from from second inclusion - this is OK
                      //       at least as long as declarations are the same

int main()
{
    return the_answer();
}
```

If on the other hand there will be definitions it will cause an error:

```
int the_answer(void)  // <-- from first inclusion - OK so far
{
    return 42;
}

int the_answer(void)  // <-- from second inclusion
{                     //     error: redefinition of 'the_answer'
    return 42;
}

int main()
{
    return the_answer();
}
```

Comment: Definitions in headers will cause linking errors anyway once you use the same header from multiple files, so don't do it.

Answer (score 0):

It's normal that most header start with

```
#ifndef _HEADERFILENAME_H_
#define _HEADERFILENAME_H_
```

and end with the following line:

```
#endif
```

If you include a header two times, the second time your programm won't include the full header again because of the `#ifndef`, `#define` and `#endif`