# Multiple definitions when compiling/linking

Tags: c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Repeated Multiple Definition Errors from including same header in multiple cpps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/223771/repeated-multiple-definition-errors-from-including-same-header-in-multiple-cpps)

I'm hitting the following error when compiling a third-party src:

```
.libs/lib_udf_la-udf.o:(.rodata+0x240): multiple definition of `SHIFT_TABLE'
.libs/lib_udf_la-hll.o:(.rodata+0x0): first defined here
```

The project is set up with autotools; my `Makefile.ag` references the following:

```
SOURCES = hll.c udf.c udf.h
```

- hll.c references hll.h
- udf.c references hll.h
- hll.h has some `const` like this:
- hll.h has the `#ifndef HLL_H ... #endif` thing to avoid double defs

  int const SHIFT_TABLE[1024] = {...}

I don't understand why I'm hitting multiple definitions, I'm guessing it has to do with the link step, but it is a long time since I dabbled with C.

Here's the cc/link output for reference:

```
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/mping/workspace/monetdb/MonetDB-11.13.5/sql/backends/monet5/UDF'
/bin/bash ../../../../libtool --tag=CC --mode=compile gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I../../../..  -I. -I.. -I./.. -I../../../include -I./../../../include -I../../../common -I./../../../common -I../../../storage -I./../../../storage -I../../../server -I./../../../server -I../../../../monetdb5/modules/atoms -I./../../../../monetdb5/modules/atoms -I../../../../monetdb5/modules/kernel -I./../../../../monetdb5/modules/kernel -I../../../../monetdb5/mal -I./../../../../monetdb5/mal -I../../../../monetdb5/modules/mal -I./../../../../monetdb5/modules/mal -I../../../../monetdb5/optimizer -I./../../../../monetdb5/optimizer -I../../../../clients/mapilib -I./../../../../clients/mapilib -I../../../../common/options -I./../../../../common/options -I../../../../common/stream -I./../../../../common/stream -I../../../../gdk -I./../../../../gdk  -DLIBUDF  -g -O2   -c -o lib_udf_la-hll.lo `test -f 'hll.c' || echo './'`hll.c
libtool: compile:  gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I../../../.. -I. -I.. -I./.. -I../../../include -I./../../../include -I../../../common -I./../../../common -I../../../storage -I./../../../storage -I../../../server -I./../../../server -I../../../../monetdb5/modules/atoms -I./../../../../monetdb5/modules/atoms -I../../../../monetdb5/modules/kernel -I./../../../../monetdb5/modules/kernel -I../../../../monetdb5/mal -I./../../../../monetdb5/mal -I../../../../monetdb5/modules/mal -I./../../../../monetdb5/modules/mal -I../../../../monetdb5/optimizer -I./../../../../monetdb5/optimizer -I../../../../clients/mapilib -I./../../../../clients/mapilib -I../../../../common/options -I./../../../../common/options -I../../../../common/stream -I./../../../../common/stream -I../../../../gdk -I./../../../../gdk -DLIBUDF -g -O2 -c hll.c  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/lib_udf_la-hll.o
/bin/bash ../../../../libtool --tag=CC --mode=compile gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I../../../..  -I. -I.. -I./.. -I../../../include -I./../../../include -I../../../common -I./../../../common -I../../../storage -I./../../../storage -I../../../server -I./../../../server -I../../../../monetdb5/modules/atoms -I./../../../../monetdb5/modules/atoms -I../../../../monetdb5/modules/kernel -I./../../../../monetdb5/modules/kernel -I../../../../monetdb5/mal -I./../../../../monetdb5/mal -I../../../../monetdb5/modules/mal -I./../../../../monetdb5/modules/mal -I../../../../monetdb5/optimizer -I./../../../../monetdb5/optimizer -I../../../../clients/mapilib -I./../../../../clients/mapilib -I../../../../common/options -I./../../../../common/options -I../../../../common/stream -I./../../../../common/stream -I../../../../gdk -I./../../../../gdk  -DLIBUDF  -g -O2   -c -o lib_udf_la-udf.lo `test -f 'udf.c' || echo './'`udf.c
libtool: compile:  gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I../../../.. -I. -I.. -I./.. -I../../../include -I./../../../include -I../../../common -I./../../../common -I../../../storage -I./../../../storage -I../../../server -I./../../../server -I../../../../monetdb5/modules/atoms -I./../../../../monetdb5/modules/atoms -I../../../../monetdb5/modules/kernel -I./../../../../monetdb5/modules/kernel -I../../../../monetdb5/mal -I./../../../../monetdb5/mal -I../../../../monetdb5/modules/mal -I./../../../../monetdb5/modules/mal -I../../../../monetdb5/optimizer -I./../../../../monetdb5/optimizer -I../../../../clients/mapilib -I./../../../../clients/mapilib -I../../../../common/options -I./../../../../common/options -I../../../../common/stream -I./../../../../common/stream -I../../../../gdk -I./../../../../gdk -DLIBUDF -g -O2 -c udf.c  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/lib_udf_la-udf.o
/bin/bash ../../../../libtool --tag=CC   --mode=link gcc -DLIBUDF  -g -O2  -module -avoid-version  -o lib_udf.la -rpath /usr/local/lib/monetdb5 lib_udf_la-hll.lo lib_udf_la-udf.lo  ../../../../monetdb5/tools/libmonetdb5.la ../../../../gdk/libbat.la 
libtool: link: gcc -shared  -fPIC -DPIC  .libs/lib_udf_la-hll.o .libs/lib_udf_la-udf.o   -Wl,-rpath -Wl,/home/mping/workspace/monetdb/MonetDB-11.13.5/monetdb5/tools/.libs -Wl,-rpath -Wl,/home/mping/workspace/monetdb/MonetDB-11.13.5/gdk/.libs ../../../../monetdb5/tools/.libs/libmonetdb5.so ../../../../gdk/.libs/libbat.so  -O2   -pthread -Wl,-soname -Wl,lib_udf.so -o .libs/lib_udf.so
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you define array `int const SHIFT_TABLE[1024] = {...}` in the header file. and then you make reference to the header file in 2 `c` file in the same project It's like of defining the array twice in the 2 `c` files. and that's the cause of your problem.

Even If you use `#ifndef` that's will not avoid your preprocess to include the definition in the second `C` file

From [Preprocessor #ifndef](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9690212/preprocessor-ifndef):

> Standard headers may be included in any order; each may be included
>   more than once in a given scope, with no effect different from being
>   included only once

You can check that in the preprocess code you will find that the array is defined twice and that's wrong. you can generate your preprocess code with `gcc -E`

the `#ifndef` works only when you check the constant macro in different header files and not in the same header file

To avoid that problem you can define your array in one of the `c` file. And you define the array as `extern` in the header file

**In one of the C files**:

```
int const SHIFT_TABLE[1024] = {...};
```

**In the header file:**

```
extern int const SHIFT_TABLE[1024];
```

Comment: The compilation step does work, but when running the program it gives an error. Unfortunately, I cannot get any more details about the error, since it's a third party app.

Comment: Try to provide a small code which reproduce your problem in order to help you